# avoid MySQL query from eating unnecessary bandwidth

Tags: php, mysql

I am concerned about optimizing my queries as far as the amount of data that is sent back from the database after doing a query.

Let's say that I have 2 tables. One called ***"artists"*** and another called ***"albums"***.

Let's say "***artists"*** table columns are: **id** and **name**

while ***"albums"*** table columns are: **id**, **artist_id**, **title**

Let's say that I want a page to diplay the artist's name as the heading. And then below that, I want to display a list of the artist's albums.

I can get that done easily by doing something like:

```
SELECT artists.name AS artist_name, albums.title AS album_title
LEFT JOIN albums
ON albums.artist_id = artists.id
WHERE artists.id = 3;
```

This would give me a result that could look something like:

```
artist_name         |   album_title
                    |
Justin Bieber       |   My First Crappy Album
Justin Bieber       |   Another Crappy Album
Justin Bieber       |   Yet Another Crappy Album
```

The problem with this result is that it gives me back the artist name multiple times, when I only really need it once. I am concerned that this way of doing things is not very efficient. Especially if the artist already has plenty of albums. I could be wrong about this, and if I am, someone please correct me.

In any case, would there be a better way of doing this? One where I don't have to retrieve the artist name multiple times?

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't about that "optimization". If it makes you feel any better, put the album title on the left with the artist name on the right. This is the kind of stuff you get back from queries, know what I mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the aggregate functions.

```
SELECT ar.name AS artist_name, GROUP_CONCAT(al.title) AS album_titles
FROM artists ar, albums al
WHERE ar.id = al.artist_id
AND ar.id = 3
GROUP BY artist_name;
```

This should give you something like:

```
artist_name         |   album_titles
Justin Bieber       |   Album1, Album2, Album3
```

I haven't used this command in a while, but you can find more documentation on it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Also, I prefer to list my tables in the FROM clause and use the WHERE clause to join them, but it's the same as your JOIN above... just a different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Then do two seperate requests.
First request the artist name

```
SELECT name
FROM artists
WHERE id = 3
```

Then the album titles..

```
SELECT title
FROM albums
WHERE artist_id = 3
```

I don't know about any bandwith logging inside php, but you can calculate witch way is the fastest in executing using `microtime()`